# Setting a specific date that is inbetween two dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a cell (lets call it 'Cell Z') that has the 25th of a month set as a date. This date has to be in-between two date ranges.

For example:

```
Cell A - Start date = 15th January 2015
Cell B - End date   = 15th February 2015
```

**In this scenario Cell Z should be set to 25th January 2015.**

When Cell A and B changes, for example:

```
Cell A - Start date = 15th February 2015
Cell B - End date   = 15th March 2015
```

**In this scenario Cell Z should automatically update to 25th February 2015.**

What logic do I write in Cell Z to achieve this?

Comment: Both of your examples would be satisfied with a simple `=A1+10`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
=EOMONTH(A1,-(DAY(A1)<26))+25
```